# Автоматизация выполнения SQL скриптов на серверах

Tags: java, sql-server, любой-язык

Есть несколько MS SQL серверов подключение к которым осуществляется через OpenVPN. Необходимо автоматизировать выполнение SQL скриптов к базам данных серверов с удалённого компьютера. Что-бы не подключатся ко всем серверам для того что-бы выполнить один SQL скрипт. Выполняю скрипты через Enterprise Manager.

Например вышел скрипт с доработкой и нужно его прикрутить к 15 серверам. Ручная часть работы состоит в том что нужно подключатся к каждому серверу и запускать скрипт к базе данных в Enterprise Manager.

Comment: А база данных какая ? по  Enterprise Manager я конечно догадываюсь, что это видимо oracle. если так то вам надо установить клиент oracle, настроить соединение (в tnsnames.ora)  и использовать sqlplus

Comment: @Mike По какому критерию какая база данных? Я там без проблем подключусь удалённо?

Comment: Ну СУБД какая, Oracle, MS Sql, MySql, postgresql ? вообще любые БД имеющие сервер позволяют подключаться удаленно. И все имеют командлайновые утилиты. А вот без проблем подключитесь или с проблемами - это хз. бывают нюансы

Comment: @Mike То есть мне искать инструмент удалённого администрирования от разработчиков?

Comment: разумеется. это средство всегда идет в комплекте с БД и чаще всего так же включено в ее клиентскую версию

Comment: А смысл удаленного подключения в чем? В чем состоит ручная часть работы и что именно Вы хотите автоматизировать? Если ручных действий вообще не предполагается и заранее известен sql-script, то не проще ли на стороне серверов создать обслуживающие sql-server-jobs для запуска по расписанию? Детализируйте вопрос.

Comment: @MikhailGrebnev Например вышел скрипт с доработкой и нужно его прикрутить к 15 серверам. Ручная часть работы состоит в том что нужно подключатся к каждому серверу и запускать скрипт к базе данных в Enterprise Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Из постановки по комментариям**

Периодически появляются новые SQL-скрипты, которые, надо проливать на 15-ти серверах.

1. `VPN` из постановки опускаю, т.к. на задачу это принципиально не
   влияет, т.к. с помощью `VPN` или напрямую, но Вы подключились к сети с
   этими 15-ти серверами.
2. `"Enterprise Manager"` из постановки опускаю,
       т.к. `"Enterprise Manager"` - это всего лишь утилита, которая не
       нужна для автоматизации процесса проливки `SQL-скриптов`.
3. `Sql-script-файлы` не нужно заливать на `sql-серверы`, нужно просто считать содержимое sql-script-файла, затем подключиться к sql-серверу и выполнить скрипт удаленно.

**Решение**

Если хочется реализовать это на java, то я бы предложил написать небольшое консольное приложение (`jar`), которое мониторит определенную `директорию` на машине. В эту `директорию` подкладываете `sql-скрипт`. `Jar-приложение` периодически опрашивает директорию, видит новый `sql-скрипт`, затем лезет в некий свой `конфиг-файл` и читает оттуда `список ConnectionStrings серверов` на которых нужно прогнать найденный `SQL-скрипт`. Вариантов реализации - куча. Главное понимать какие у Вас есть предпочтения по реализации и как Вас технологически ограничивают по данной задаче.

**Последовательность реализации**

1. Подключиться к sql-server. Для начинающего, проще всего это делать через jdbc-драйвер. Например: [Concept connecting to SQL using Java](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java).
2. Считать файл из заранее известной директории. Например: [Эволюция Java на примере чтения строк из файла](https://habrahabr.ru/post/269667/)
3. Выполнить sql-скрипт на сервере в подключенном connection (см. п.1).
4. Когда заработает всё, что описано выше, можно усложнять приложение, добавить по расписанию сканирование директории для sql-скриптов и т.п.

Comment: Идея ясна. Требуются. Я хочу что-бы консольное приложение закидывало файл на сервер а потом запускала sql скрипт на заранее определённую базу данных в программе или в самом скрипте. Как забросить файл я думаю что справлюсь, но как мне его запустить? Мне нужны рекомендации или пример реализации, так что-бы я справился. Платформы Windows Server 2003, 2008,  SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 4. Как подключится в программе я не знаю, не имеет значения. На сервер я подключаюсь через RDP, к файловой системе через Проводник или TotalCMD, может даже можно сетевой диск подключить, не пробовал.

Comment: Все понял. Вечером напишу пример реализации.

Comment: Mikhail Grebenev Добро

Comment: Mikhail Grebenev Вы заб ы\и ли?

Comment: Не смог до компа добраться, прошу прощения, в понедельник напишу.

Comment: Mikhail Grebenev Добро, если что, пишите в комментарии

Comment: @Здравсвтуй т е

Comment: Добрый день. Что-нибудь пояснить нужно?

Comment: Вы же обещали что напишите пример реализации

Comment: Задача в целом состоит из нескольких простых вещей - я дал ссылки на эти простые вещи. Ваша задача прочитать статьи и выполнить пошагово предложенный мною план. Выкладывать сюда скомпонованный проект, который делает всё - это не вписывается в тематику сайта. Начните решать задачу и задавайте конкретные отдельные новые вопросы на этом сайте. Лучше задавать вопросы с примерами кода, чтобы было легче Вам помочь. С чем конкретно сейчас проблема? Что не получается?

Comment: Я не видел ваше обновление ответа. Буду пробовать реализовать, спасибо. Если будут вопросы можно Вам здесь написать?

Comment: Да, конечно можно и здесь. Или создавайте новый вопрос со ссылкой на этот. Чем больше информации будет у отвечающих - тем более конкретные ответы Вы сможете получить.

Answer (score 1):

В случае MS SQL Server логичнее использовать Power Shell скрипт который будет запускаться по расписанию или вручную, как удобнее.